# Ajax: does setting timeout always override the browser's timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It seems to be possible to set a timeout value when doing an Ajax request in plain javascript. see [How to detect timeout on an AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) call in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018705/how-to-detect-timeout-on-an-ajax-xmlhttprequest-call-in-the-browser)

It is also possible when using jQuery's ajax implementation, & other similar frameworks I assume. see [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Browsers seem to have rather vague specification regarding their default timeout. see [Browser Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts)

Hence one might "hey, I'm going to set a timeout to my ajax request so all the users will have the same timeout".

But then, the next question follow: would it actually override the browser's timeout in all cases?

When I say "all" cases, I mean for instance, if the browser timeout value is smaller than your ajax request timeout value.

I suspect it does not.

And I also suspect it is best practice to always have a timeout error handler to make sure that whatever happens you can display a relevant message that will save hours of work to your support team, & money to your company. see [Determine if $.ajax error is a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout/3543713)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on this http://morgb.blogspot.de/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html I would guess "not at least on firefox. This answer claims there is no way to override. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192375/timeout-behavior-of-different-browsers

Comment: Do you know the "complete", "success" and "error" settings of AJAX yet? I mean, why you gonna need a timeOut function when you have the "complete" setting that response when the request is end?

Comment: @FernandoUrban yes I do. The question is about setting a same timeout value regardless of the browser (browser's timeout). Not about acting according to timeout (whether you do it in "complete" or "error").

Answer (score 6):

It is an interesting question, I made some experiments in Chrome 59.0 and Firefox 54.0 using a 10min delay service as the backend.

After some test setting the timeout on the client to 10 minutes I had an error response with text status "error" after 300 seconds (5 minutes) in both browsers, so at least for these two browsers **it is not possible to override the internal timeout value**. I am assuming the same behavior for the remaining browsers in the market.

My test script: (similar results for vanilla JavaScript)

```
var st = new Date();  
  $.ajax({
      url: "https//mysitewith10minresponse.com/foobar",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      timeout: 600000, 
      success: function(response) { console.log(response); },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
          st = (new Date() - st)/1000;
          alert("Text Status " + textStatus + ", diff: " + st + " seconds");          
      }
  });
```

Comment: Although it's a fundamental part of the answer, but I'm not clear on what you mean with:  "300 seconds = 2 minutes" ??  could you please check that again?